# Non nullable property warning in DBcontext class for dbset property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, warnings, dbcontext, dbset

I have my database context class as below

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) 
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers;
    public DbSet<Order> Orders;
}
```

it warns saying

```
non-nullable property 'Orders' must contain a non-null value when exiting the constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable
```

I have two options in hand to resolve but not sure which is good.

Option 1) make the property as nullable

```
public DbSet<Order>? Orders;
```

Option 2) set the property to empty set in constructor

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) 
    {
        this.Orders =  this.Set<Order>();
    }
```

Which one is the best option to resolve this warning and which also support test cases. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hint the C# 8.0 nullable reference system that a property is initalized using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342964/how-can-i-hint-the-c-sharp-8-0-nullable-reference-system-that-a-property-is-init)

Comment: Take note that `Customers`  and `Orders` need to be properties (with `{ get; set; }`), as shown in the linked answer. If it's not a property, it won't be initialized by EF.

Comment: According to the [ms-docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset), this should be fixed in .NET 7. :)

Answer (score 7):

Because a `DbSet<T>` is (for all practical purposes) guaranteed to be populated by EF once you create a context, you can set it to `null!` without changing the actual type:

```cs
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;} = null!;
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;} = null!;
```

This will satisfy the non-nullable requirements without also upsetting EF.

`null!` is essentially a way of telling the compiler "I know you think this is going to be null, but I know better and know it won't be null by the time I need it - so don't warn me about it."

Comment: True, but they also need to be properties. EF won't initialize fields. Better yet, vote for the duplicate closure.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with C#11 (.NET 7) one can use the `required` modifier to mark that a property needs to be set by an object initializer. Since we don't manually instance the DbContext, we can therefore use it in this case:

```cs
public required DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
public required DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;}
```

Edit: another option [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset) is:

```cs
public DbSet<Customer> Customers => Set<Customer>();
public DbSet<Order> Orders => Set<Orders>()
```

Comment: But when you do it on a DbContext, it emits an error: error CS9035: Required member 'xxx' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.

Comment: I guess you didn't forget about the constructor (delegating to `base`)? But there's anyway the second method which you could try.